# ASP.NET Core: How to disable logging for Static Files?

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-logging

I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Angular 8 for my project,

I am serving angular Static Files from my .net core project using SPA Extensions Like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options =>
    {
        options.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
   app.UseSpa(spa =>
   {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
   });
}
```

My problem is that my logs contains every request regarding back-end or front-end server,
That is, I find a lot of logs to routes like:

https://example.com/index.html

https://example.com/assets/images/logo.svg

Which is really annoying, I don't want front-end server logs (static files)!

I have one general logger in my custom middle-ware defined like this:

```
public CustomRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _next = next;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("My Logger");
}
```

I can disable its logs from appsettings.json file like this:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "Hangfire": "None",
      "My Logger": "None"
    }
  }
```

But the problem is that this logger is used for all requests to system, which includes both front-end (static files) & back-end (API) logs, and I need only to disable logging for front-end logs.

Is there a way to filter logs?

Comment: `still got those logs` Have you checked in which middleware/service write these logs of static files? still from Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware? You can share the screenshot of the logs, so that we can help troubleshot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan I have a custom middleware, with a logger in its constructor:
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("My Logger");

I found out that this logger is the one responsible for all logs, and I can prevent it from appsettings using "My Logger": "None",

But the problem now is that I need back-end server logs alone, without front-end server logs, and this logger log both, I am trying to find some way to filter logs

Comment: If possible, you can try to check if it is static file related logs using regx in your custom logger code logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by adding the code "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "None" to the logging section of the appsetting.json file